# Is there a current version of PCManFM-Qt that's ready to go?

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, qt, lxqt, pcmanfm-qt

I'm currently running 0.17.0, but on GitHub the [latest version is 1.3](https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt/releases) - so I'm wayyy behind. However, when I try `apt`, it tells me I have the latest version. Snap doesn't have it, neither does Flatpak.

I can download the project from [GitHub](https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt), but I have no idea how to compile it for use. I've googled, but the instructions I've found don't seem to match what came from GitHub.

How can I install the latest version (1.3) of PCManFM-Qt on my system?

System specifications:

- Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.3
- Kernel Version: 5.15.0-75-generic (64-bit)
- Graphics Platform: X11
- Processors: 4 × Intel® Xeon® CPU E31225 @ 3.10GHz
- Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
- Graphics Processor: NV167

Comment: Even if you're using a different *flavor* than Lubuntu, the Lubuntu *backports* I mention in my *answer* will still work.. Lubuntu, Kubuntu and Ubuntu Studio work closely together (*you'll see that by peeking in the -devel rooms on IRC*) as we share resources & the upkeep of Qt5, `calamares` (Lubuntu & Ubuntu Studio only for this) etc.. If you're using multiple *backports* (eg. Kubuntu backports + Lubuntu backports) we really only QA Ubuntu repositories though we do discuss some things as to what we'll do (via backports) first, we don't QA multiple backports together on a single system.

Comment: as example... after one of our (as in Lubuntu) *backports* blogs, the first comment (*within ~5 mins of the publish*) was from a Kubuntu *developer* who detected something we missed.... You likely know this, but I'm using Lubuntu examples *primarily* as its a team I'm in... in practice Ubuntu Studio (using KDE Plasma thus Qt5 + KF5 etc) is closer to Kubuntu than we at Lubuntu are (*though a recent Kubuntu Council member to step down is now on the Lubuntu Council.. - we're all part of the larger Ubuntu family*)

Answer (score 1):

You've not provided the essential release details.

### (a) Lubuntu 21.10 with LXQt 0.17

You're using an *unsupported* release of Lubuntu, thus upgrades are **not** available as we don't support it. Lubuntu 21.10 is EOL

- https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-21-10-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/
- https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/

I suggest you re-install a *supported* system.

### (b) Lubuntu 22.04 with LXQt 0.17

Lubuntu 22.04 that released with LXQt 0.17 as was [announced](https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/), with the older LXQt from the prior release for the reasons as documented about by the Lubuntu team on the Lubuntu discourse (*it was highlighted as a plea for more contributors!*).

To upgrade it, you can use *backports* as the Lubuntu team have documented in numerous posts

- https://lubuntu.me/category/release/backports/

basically

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-dev/backports`

but I'll recommend you read the documentation, and warnings provided by the Lubuntu team.

LXQt 1.2 will provide `pcmanfm-qt` package `1.2.1-0ubuntu3~ppa1` (ie. *version 1.2 as found currently in Lubuntu 23.04*) being the app which handles much of the LXQt desktop seen on screen & doubles as a file-manager (*written by [PCMan](https://github.com/PCMan)*). The PPA could be used only to provide that package too.

*Note: Upgrading to LXQt 1.2 or beyond will prevent you from being able to release-upgrade a 22.04 system to 22.10; only the earlier provided backported versions allowed for this (when backports increased beyond what 22.10 provided upgrade was no longer available); this will not impact upgrades to 24.04 or LTS to LTS in the future as we'll not upgrade backports that far.*

*This answer was written before your Kubuntu detail was known, `pcmanfm-qt` being such a critical component of LXQt; to me the question related to LXQt thus my chosen wording; but it will apply too if you only want selected parts of LXQt 1.2 (such as `pcmanfm-qt`), though the contents of the backports PPA was QA tested only as a whole on a Lubuntu/LXQt system given that's what it was packaged for*

**Update: LXQt 1.3 & `pcmanfm-qt` on 22.04**

The Lubuntu backports PPA was updated to [LXQt 1.3](https://Zhttps://launchpad.net/%7Elubuntu-dev/+archive/ubuntu/backports), which of course includes `pcmanfm-qt` (1.3 or `1.3.0-0ubuntu1~ppa1`, being a key component of the displayed LXQt desktop seen by users) as can be read about here - https://lubuntu.me/jammy-backports-22-04-3-lxqt-1-3/

The Lubuntu team have made a decision not to support upgrading 22.04 to 23.04 etc where *backports* are utilized, thus usage of *backports* on 22.04 can achieve a newer LXQt than provided by [22.10 (*now EOL*)](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-reached-end-of-life-on-july-20-2023/4310) OR 23.04 (*LXQt 1.3 being the LXQt currently found on mantic or what will be 23.10*).

Comment: I didn't realize they were so closely tied together.

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-75-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Xeon® CPU E31225 @ 3.10GHz
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NV167

Comment: LXQt 1.3 will go into Lubuntu *mantic* or 23.10; however we may **not** put that in *backports* (so as available for 22.04 users), as it may make it harder for them to *release-upgrade* to 24.04; then again as we're expecting 24.04 to have a higher version of LXQt and thus the issue I'm *alluding* to here won't exist - we can (*if we've resources to do it of course*).  Currently only 1.2 is available as per my answer.

Comment: FYI:   1.3 is being packaged currently.. alas some of the *build* failed for *jammy* earlier today (*my local timezone*) but it'll continue... along with Qt6 & LXQt 2(*alpha*) via PPA.. but we'll do some *smoke* testing before we publish anything..

Comment: LXQt 1.4 (*which of course includes key component `pcmanfm-qt`*) is now for users of the current *development* release (*noble* or what will be 24.04 on release), as well as users of Lubuntu 22.04 LTS (https://lubuntu.me/jammy-backports-22-04-3-lxqt-1-4/) or Lubuntu 23.10 (https://lubuntu.me/mantic-lxqt-1-4/).  If using 23.10 please note the *warnings* as we intend removing or *disabling* that PPA for *mantic* once 24.04 is *stable* (LXQt 1.4 is already on *noble* being the key version)